# Use function to toggle div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to write a function that when called toggles my 'p' tag.

I know I could use

```
$(this).click(function(){
    // Run my function here
});
```

But i want it as a function so it can be called and I can use it in multiple projects.

Can anybody see where im going wrong with this?

```
(function(toggle){
    $(this).on("click", function(){
        $(this).parent().find('p').slideToggle();
    });
})
```

Here the example code: http://jsfiddle.net/UBaSq/

Comment: you have not added any selectors for the click handler

Answer (score 3):

```
toggler = function() {
  $(this).parent().find("p").slideToggle();
}

// someElement will be passed as "this" to toggler
$("someElement").on("click", toggler); 

// Call toggler right away
toggler.apply($("someElement"));
```

Comment: Thanks @Mishik, Can I ask, what does the .apply do?

Comment: `functionX.apply(obj, [arg1, arg2, ...])` == call functionX with arguments `arg1, arg2,...` and set `this` to `obj`. Similar: `functionX.call(obj, arg1, arg2,...)` == same as apply, but you need to list the arguments instead of supplying them via array.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('a').on("click", function(){
        $(this).parent().find('p').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tAMhE/)